# Selenium Try/Catch Error

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, try-catch

I am using Selenium with Java an facing the following problem.

When I use the following code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(firstNameXPath)).sendKeys(firstName);
```

I am able to successfully select the appropriate locator on the page and get no errors.

However, when I pass the locator to a method to check if the locator exists first and only then send keys I always get an error (locator not being present).

This is the method I am using:

```
    public boolean IsXPathPresent(String XPath)
{

    try 
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPath));
        System.out.println("Selector: " + XPath + " found");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        System.out.println(XPath + " Selector Not Present");
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am passing `firstNameXPath` to the method `IsXPathPresent`.

For some reason my program always outputs "Selector Not Present" which means it is always executing the catch part. But why ? The selector is present on page..

Is there something wrong with my try/catch block?

Thanks

Comment: Once remove try,catch and check..which exception is it throwing??

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  but I don't see why it would throw a null pointer..

Comment: may be that xpath/driver is null. Once check it by printing those two in s.o.p. No need to catch any exception here. You should be careful about it while passing xpath.

Comment: OK.. I found the error.. I was passing the driver as argument when instantiating class so it was null then I fixed it now.. @Sarith G do you work with Selenium a lot? I want to speak with you about something.. How can we get in touch?

Comment: I have worked for one month. Later I changed my platform.

Comment: May I ask what did you change to and why?

Comment: I am working on Android thats all I can tell.

Comment: Anyhow you can ask me if you have any doubts in selenium.

Comment: Thanks.. How can I contact you?